# #define in assert.h example

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am trying to understand #define processing better and looking at an asssert.h file as a simple example.  The code is:

```
# define assert(EX) (void)((EX) || (__assert (#EX, __FILE__, __LINE__),0))
```

I'm confused about the OR expression.  I assume this line is saying that if the expression is true, do nothing, if false, call the __assert function.  But how does the preprocessor process the line and where does the OR determine the definition of assert?  And why the (void) cast?

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: The OR is an example of Short-Circuit Evaluation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: "*But how does the preprocessor process the line and where does the OR determine the definition of assert?*" I have no idea what you're asking here.

Comment: `EX` is the expression being asserted. The preprocessor does exactly what (hopefully) think it does: expand that substitution using `EX` as appropriate into your code. If you thought like a preprocessor and tried some substitutions yourself it will probably make more sense, assuming you understand how [stringizing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html) works.

Comment: You should create a small test file, and look at the preprocessor output. With gcc or clang, the `-E` option shows you the preprocessor output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in this case the preprocessor is not evaluating anything, it's just
doing a textual replacement of the macro with the passed expression.

Let's say you have the variable `int x = 2;`

When you do `assert(x == 3)` the preprocessor expands this to

```
(void)((x == 3) || __assert("x == 3", "test.c", 13),0);
```

Because `x` is 2, `x==3` is evaluated to false and the the right side must be
evaluated (see [Short-Circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)). When the right side
is evaluted (assuming that the source is `text.c` and you did that on line 13)

```
__assert("x == 3", "text.c", 13),0
```

`__assert` will print something like *x==3 failed on text.c:13*. The comma operator is used
so continue evaluation the next expression and return that value as the result
of the whole expression (see [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)), in this case 0, so the result of

```
((x == 3) || __assert("x == 3", "test.c", 13),0);
```

is 0. `__assert` might be a function or another macro, but since you haven't
shown the definition of `__assert`, I'm treating it as a function.

If however `x` were 3, then `x == 3` would evalute to true, and the right side won't be
evaluated at all, because `||` evaluates to true if either side is true, and if
the left side is already true, then there is no need to evaluate the right side
(again, see [Short-Circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)).

The `(void)` is there to silence the compiler when you compile with all warning,
the compiler might warn you about not used variables.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.  Sorry for the inarticulateness of the question.  The difficulty for me lies in thinking in terms of preprocessor substitution vs code executing.  But your answer helps immensely.